# Can I use a convolution filter instead of a dense layer for clasification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I was reading a decent paper [S-DCNet](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/from-open-set-to-closed-set-counting-objects) and I fell upon a section (page3,table1,classifier) where a convolution layer has been used on the feature map in order to produce a binary classification output as part of an internal process. Since I am a noob and when someone talks to me about classification I automatically make a synapse relating to FCs combined with softmax, I started wondering ... Is this a possible thing to do? Can indeed a convolutional layer be used to classify a binary outcome? The whole concept triggered my imagination so much that I insist on getting answers...

**Honestly, how does this actually work? What is the difference between using a convolution filter instead of a fully connected layer for classification purposes?**

Edit (Uncertain answer on how does it work): *I asked a colleague and he told me that using a filter of the same shape as the length-width shape of the feature map at the current stage, may lead to a learnable binary output (considering that you also reduce the #channels of the feature map to a single channel). But I still don't understand the motivations behind such a technique ..*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using convolutions as FCs can be done (for example) with filters of spatial size (1,1) and with depth of the same size as the FC input size.

The resulting feature map would be of the same size as the input feature map, but each pixel would be the output of a "FC" layer whose weights are the weights of the shared 1x1 conv filter.

This kind of thing is used mainly for semantic segmentation, meaning classification per pixel. [U-net](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597) is a good example if memory serves.

---

Also see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194142/what-does-1x1-convolution-mean-in-a-neural-network).
Also note that 1x1 convolutions have [other uses](https://machinelearningmastery.com/introduction-to-1x1-convolutions-to-reduce-the-complexity-of-convolutional-neural-networks/) as well.
[paperswithcode](https://paperswithcode.com/task/semantic-segmentation) probably some of the nets there use this trick.

Comment: I see .. So it enables you to classify in a pixel wise manner the input feature map so that you have a 2D feature map and each pixel denotes the foreground/background classification prediction.. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure .. well .. having checked the paper I found out that this is what it actually does in a more complicated manner I suppose .. It does treat it in a binary classification manner, but for multi-class classification , by maintaining a #classes amount of filters-channels in order to have a binary classification output for each single channel of the feature map (that is for each class individually). In the first chance , I 'll study the links you sent in depth, Thank you!